# Angular 6 - trying to pass a function to a function in another class

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table where I click a button on a row to update a bool field on the row.
I then want to refresh the table.
What I have below is:

SaveItem - sets the value I want update, then passes the object, id and a function to the function doing the call.

editItem - makes the call and updates the item, but I then want it to then run the function passed in, which is the last function below, getItems, which would re-populate the object the table is based on.

It fails on the last line of editItem with

```
TypeError: getItems is not a function
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
SaveItem(flag: boolean) {
    this.item$.Published = flag;
    this.edit.editItem(this.item$, this.id, this.getItems(this.items$));
  }


editItem(item, id, getItems) {
    const url = this.apiUrl + '/tables/Items/' + id
    this.http.patch(url, item, httpOptions).subscribe((data) => getItems(data));
  }


getItems(itemList: Item[]): void{
  this.data.getItems()
  .subscribe(data => this.items$ = data);
}
```

Comment: should it not be `this.getItems(data)` in the `editItem` subscribe?

Comment: I don't think so, as getItems is passed in the constructor and not a class variable

Comment: @DarkW1nter that sounds obscure, can you post the entire class? Including constructor. In your code example I also see nowhere a mention of `getEvents`

Comment: What is `getEvents`?

Comment: sorry ignore getEvents, copy & paste error, should be getItems

Comment: Could you please provide a stackblitz?

Comment: you are not passing a function reference to the `editItem` method, but the returned value of the function, which in this case is `undefined`. It's too hard to tell what you are trying to do, but if you really want to pass a function you should do it like this: `this.edit.editItem(this.item$, this.id, this.getItems)`. Without actually calling the function. Be aware of losing the correct `this` context though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare the callback as a flat function, not the result of the function. See this little tidbit, which you can run on the Typescript Scratchpad [by clicking here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Item%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Published%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Observable%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20subscribe(callback%3A%20(data%3A%20Array%3CItem%3E)%20%3D%3E%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20callback(new%20Array%3CItem%3E())%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20apiUrl%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20http%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20patch%3A%20(url%2C%20item%2C%20httpOptions)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Observable()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20item%24%20%3D%20new%20Item()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20items%24%3A%20Item%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%27someid%27%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20edit%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20editItem%3A%20(item%3A%20any%2C%20id%3A%20string%2C%20callback%3A%20(data%3A%20Item%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20THIS%20IS%20THE%20IMPORTANT%20CHANGE%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.editItem(item%2C%20id%2C%20callback)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getItems%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Observable()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20editItem(item%2C%20id%2C%20getItems)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20httpOptions%3A%20any%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20url%20%3D%20this.apiUrl%20%2B%20%27%2Ftables%2FItems%2F%27%20%2B%20id%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.http.patch(url%2C%20item%2C%20httpOptions).subscribe((data)%20%3D%3E%20this.getItems(data))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getItems(itemList%3A%20Item%5B%5D)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.data.getItems()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.subscribe(data%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20this.items%24%20%3D%20data%3B%20alert(%22Hey!%20I%20got%20called%22)%3B%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SaveItem(flag%3A%20boolean)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.item%24.Published%20%3D%20flag%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.edit.editItem(this.item%24%2C%20this.id%2C%20this.getItems)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0D%0Atest.SaveItem(true)%3B%0D%0A). I did put a couple comments like "// THIS IS THE IMPORTANT CHANGE" where this applies.

```
class Item {
    Published: boolean
}

class Observable {
    subscribe(callback: (data: Array<Item>) => any) {
        callback(new Array<Item>());
    }
}

class Test {

    apiUrl: string;
    http = {
        patch: (url, item, httpOptions) => { 
            return new Observable();
        }
    };
    item$ = new Item();
    items$: Item[];
    id: 'someid';
    edit = {
        editItem: (item: any, id: string, callback: (data: Item[]) => void) => {
            // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT CHANGE
            return this.editItem(item, id, callback);
        }
    }
    data = {
        getItems: () => { 
            return new Observable();
        }
    };

    editItem(item, id, getItems) {
        const httpOptions: any = {};
        const url = this.apiUrl + '/tables/Items/' + id
        this.http.patch(url, item, httpOptions).subscribe((data) => this.getItems(data));
    }

    getItems(itemList: Item[]): void {
        this.data.getItems()
            .subscribe(data => { this.items$ = data; alert("Hey! I got called"); });
    }

    SaveItem(flag: boolean) {
        this.item$.Published = flag;
        // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT CHANGE
        this.edit.editItem(this.item$, this.id, this.getItems);
    }
}

let test = new Test();
test.SaveItem(true);
```